# Flutter get all the inbox sms in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, stream, sms

Please could you help me if is there any ways to get all the list of inbox sms in iOS using flutter. I tried many of the flutter packages but they are old and didn’t work. What would be the best approach?

Comment: There is no way to read messages on iOS in Flutter or any other language. iOS values user privacy and does not permit this